# Django: how to make a get param or 404 function?

Tags: python, django

I want my endpoints to throw a 404 status code WITH a message like "parameter foo not found" if the request is missing a required field.
Since i have too many endpoints, adding 3 lines of code (try, except, return) is not a happy solution for me.
That's why i want to make a function similar to get_object_or_404 from django.shortcuts, where just using the function, the request returns 404 instead of just raising an exception and crashing the server.

Taking a look to the get_object_or_404 function, i note that it does `raise Http404` and this does work, but it always returns "detail": "Not Found" ignoring any parameter i pass to the exception raising code.

Here's what i did:

```
class ParamNotFound(Exception):
    def __init__(self, param_name):
        self.param_name = param_name
        self.status_code = 404

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Param {self.param_name} not found"


def get_body_param_or_404(params, param_name: str):
    param = params.get(param_name, None)
    if param is None:
        raise ParamNotFound(f"param_name {param_name} not found")

    return param
```

But this does only raise a exception and crash the server if i dont explicitly catch it.
Is there a clean and short way to do this?

Comment: Maybe inherit from Http404 to change the message?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was more complicated that i thought.
I ended implementing a middleware, where i can catch my own exception returning a custom JsonResponse.

```
class ParamMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response) -> None:
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, ParamNotFound):
            return JsonResponse({"msg": str(exception), "status": 404})
```